# Java : using an array created in the main method in other methods and classes

Tags: java, arrays

So I've created an array in the main method that reads an input from a file and then adds it to the array and it also uses a command reader to check that the file has data left. How do I make any specific array element available to use in other methods? Take an array called array[], how do I access array[1] and use it in other methods? Thanks and sorry if this is an obvious question but I'm quite new to java.

**Edit**

Source code:

```
import java.io.File;

// Reads commands from input file

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        if (args.length < 1) {
            System.out.println("No args given.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        // reads every argument given as a filename
        for (String filename : args) {
            File file = new File(filename);
            //creating a command reader from a file
            CommandReader Reader = new CommandReader(file);

            // reads every line of the file
            while(Reader.hasNext()) {
                // gets the given command from the next line
                String[] command = reader.next();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to use these outside of the main class. I've got a command reader class that formats them in such a way as to give the commands like that but that is not important to using the array outside of the main. Thanks

```
command[0] => "add" 
command[1] => "AlbinoMilk's great adventure"
command[2] => "AlbinoMilk"
command[3] => "250"
```

Comment: Can we see the source code ? You've got array indexing right, but without context it's difficult to say more. For instance, did you mean array[0] ? (Java arrays are zero-indexed)

Comment: I've added the source code if you'd like to have a look? Thanks

Comment: You should make commands be an instance variable. As it is you are redefining it every time through the while loop. I think this should have caused a compiler error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword here is *scope*. The scope of a variable defines, where the variable is visible and can be used. Usually, the scope of a variable in Java is defined to be the innermost curly braces that are surrounding the variable definition.

There are several ways to be able to access variables outside of their current *scope*.

- When you call a method from somewhere with access to the variable, add the variable as parameter to the method. This way, the function also has access.
- Move the definition of the variable. For instance, if you have a local variable in your `main`, just move it one "level" up, so define it as a (private) member of the class instead. Now, all the functions in your class have access to it. This should only be done if it helps the class in the future or makes code more readable. Usually, try to keep the scope of variables as small as possible to increase maintainability.
- Have a variable access controller class. Classes can then *register* access of certain variables through `interface` implementations. Other classes can then access variables through this interface.
- etc.

In your case, it is best to go with the first (or second) way.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass it as a parameter to the other functions.

```
foo(int[] array) {//}
```

And call it from the main

```
foo(array1);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve that:

1. declare your array as a field in your class, outside the main method:

   ```
   public class SomeClass {
     private int[] array; 
     ...
     ...
     public static void main(String[] args) {
       array = ....
     }
     ...
   }
   ```
2. pass it as a parameter to other methods that require it

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had an ArrayList in my main method as follows: `static ArrayList<MyClass> myclass= new ArrayList<MyClass>();`. I was adding random values to it from the main method. Then I needed to access the ArrayList from another class so the way to do that, was to create a constructor in the class where I wanted to use it like this:

```
ArrayList<MyClass> myclass;
    public AnotherClass(ArrayList<MyClass> myclass) {
        this.myclass= myclass;
    }
// the ArrayList used in other methods here
```

So I could create objects of `AnotherClass` in main taking the ArrayList as an argument: `AnotherClass ac = new AnotherClass(myClass);`